# Reduce Load time of website build in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, time, load

My web application takes almost 4-5 mins to load because I loaded around 20-30 custom js files on my index page, that why Its taking too much time, I can't change routing at this point, Is their anyway to reduce the load time.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: Apart from minification and uglification, you should also consider lazy loading

Comment: Also, is this Angular or AngularJS?

Comment: code is on AngularJS

Comment: I already said I can't change routing to the lazy loading because it's too complicated now to change routing

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/).

It will analyze and show you which parts of your web are slow, and also how to improve them.

Also consider [minify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) your scripts to reduce the file size.

Comment: is their any option to reduce the time, like lazyloading alternative or cache storage?

Comment: Google PageSpeed Insights just analyzes your webpage and tells you which parts should be fixed. It doesn't do anything to your web though.